# AngularJS + Ionic - How to refresh unhide a button when ng-hide parameter change

Tags: angularjs, html, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app. When I open the app I go straight to a page where the visitor can check my products. At this point the vistor cannot see the menu button because he is no logged in (ng-hide="!user.loggedIn").

The variable user.loggedIn is treated in this page controller, where I set it value = a flag on localStorage, as show below.

When he select the products he whats to buy, I take him to sign up/sign in and then give access to him to the menu in all pages.

However, when I go to the pages where the menu was set to hide (ng-hide), the menu keeps hidden, even with my flag on localStorage changing value.

What I need is to "refresh" the controller $scope and also the button parameters, to make it unhide. How can I do this?

Thanks!

HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="Novo Pedido">    
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-comprador">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-comprador ion-navicon"
                    menu-toggle="left" ng-hide="!user.loggedIn"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
...

CONTROLLER
        $scope.user = [];
        $scope.user.loggedIn= 0;
        $scope.user.loggedIn= localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent($scope.user.loggedIn);
```

Comment: are you getting value in  $scope.user.loggedIn after login of user??what i am thinking is your failing to fetch the value from local storage after updating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this might be because ionic caches the view. You can use the various ionicview events to achieve what you want. for eg

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){ 
        $scope.user = [];
        $scope.user.loggedIn= 0;
        $scope.user.loggedIn= localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent($scope.user.loggedIn);
});
```

This is would run everytime the user enters the view.

Sometimes when model is update during a digest cycle, angular fails to update the dom. If the above does not solve you can try

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.user = [];
    $scope.user.loggedIn= 0;
    $scope.user.loggedIn= localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent($scope.user.loggedIn);

});
```

You can combine both of them

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest two things:
a. add a console log when you are updating the variable.
 for exe:

```
     $scope.user = [];
     $scope.user.loggedIn= 0;
     $scope.user.loggedIn= localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
     console.log($scope.user.loggedIn);
```

it will print the value on your console and you'll know if you are retrieving  the correct value.
b. if the value is there then try adding the following line after you update your value.

```
    $scope.user = [];
    $scope.user.loggedIn= 0;
    $scope.user.loggedIn= localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
    $scope.$apply();
```

the above statement will refresh the view for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out!